# Slack event message.im not being triggered

Tags: slack, slack-api

I'm trying to get the event to be triggered when someone sends a message on a private conversation in slack, I've already registered the event subscription (message.im) in the subscribe to bot events section, made sure that the needed scope was added (im:history), and reinstalled the app on my workspace.

Also tried signing out of the workspace and logging in again.

Yet, even if it is the admin sending a message to a user or a user sending a message to the admin (or in any other case with other users) the Event is not being triggered.

Any help or suggestion of why could this be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Please read [ask] to learn how to ask a good question. A question like this with no code is likely to be closed. It's very difficult to answer your question without seeing what you have tried.

Comment: I'm sorry, this question didn't include code because all the required steps where done on the Slack API config and scope pages. Next time I suppose I could add a screenshot or something like that, just thought it would make it less clear if I added too many images. Luckily what Jai Pandya said was exactly the information I was looking for :) thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: That makes sense. I tried to remove my down vote but it's locked in until the question is edited. If you wish to edit your question in some way I can then remove my down vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive this event when a user sends a direct message to your bot/app.

You wouldn't receive this event when a user sends a message to another user, because the bot is not a part of that conversation.

Comment: I see...is there any way to add the bot to the conversations a a listener? Or how could I get the messages for that conversation between users?

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to do an integration with slack and need to get the messages in order to show the 'New slack messages'  notification to the users. Is there another way to make that possible? To get the messages of a conversation in somehow real time?

Comment: The bot can't be a part of a DM between two users. You can subscribe to events on behalf of users though (see app config section for event subscription). For this, you'll need to use a [user token](https://api.slack.com/authentication/token-types#user) as opposed to a bot token you are currently using.

Comment: Got it, I successfully subscribed to the event on behalf of user in the app config section. Now, where or when is it going to ask for the user tokens? Or will this be triggered for every user that has obtained a token with the required scope?

Comment: Once the app is installed, for each user for whom you want this event to be fired, you'll need to individually ask permission to access the relevant scope. When the user gives you authorization, your app will start receiving these events. I'd suggest trying some apps on Slack app directory to see how other apps handle this flow.